# ERROR: Error response from daemon: datastore for scope "global" is not initialized

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I create sucsessfully a swarm, with two nodes. However when I use `docker-compose build && docker-compose up` in order to start my project it crashes erroring out this:

`ERROR: Error response from daemon: datastore for scope "global" is not initialized`

It's a very very simple process:

`docker run swarm create`

**swarm hash**:
`1477bcd7778d083e02a80c352d4f1b87`

`docker-machine create -d virtualbox --swarm --swarm-master --swarm-discovery token://1477bcd7778d083e02a80c352d4f1b87 myswarmmaster`

`docker-machine create -d virtualbox --swarm --swarm-discovery token://1477bcd7778d083e02a80c352d4f1b87 myremotenode1`

`eval $(docker-machine env --swarm myswarmmaster)`

`docker-compose build && docker-compose up`

And then I get the error:

`ERROR: Error response from daemon: datastore for scope "global" is not initialized`

I'm running docker on Fedora 25.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I did `docker swarm init` on an Ubuntu machine. What I found was that swarm tries to access port 2377 so first open up the port 2377 `sudo ufw allow 2377`
And now `docker swarm init` worked and showed a message like this

```
Swarm initialized: current node (sdf23fsd3f24fr3f2f) is now a manager.

To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:

docker swarm join \
--token SW3Wwww-1-0dfsdffsdfdsfsdfdsfdfdsfdsf-dsfsdfdsfdsfdsfd \
52.15.91.31:2377
```

The key is make sure that appropriate ports are available.
Hope this helps